# Unchecked and runtime exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception

In Java, we have checked exceptions and unchecked exceptions. Also, we have runtime exceptions. My question is -  Are all runtime exceptions unchecked exceptions and all unchecked exception are runime excepions? Means can these two words be used interchangeably?

Comment: This is not duplicate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All runtime exceptions (e.g. NullPointerException) are unchecked exceptions.

Since errors (e.g. StackOverflowError) are also unchecked exceptions, not all unchecked exceptions are runtime exceptions.

The [Java Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html) define an unchecked exception:  "The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes."

Comment: Both `java.lang.Error` and `java.lang.Exception` are subclasses of `java.lang.Throwable`, `Error` isn't a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: @tayloj what you say makes sense except the java language spec specifies otherwise.

Comment: emory is correct. I think its just confusing because of the name "error" and not exception. Thanks for clarifying my ages old doubt..

Comment: @emory Good point.  `Exception` and `Error` was a bit pedantic;  I saw the comment on the question about the possible duplicate (difference between `RuntimeException` and `Exception`) which was more about the particular classes.  This question doesn't mention those, and so it's probably about "exceptions" (lower case 'e'), as discussed in the spec.